# Add a leter to the 46th word in every line in a text file using linux

Tags: linux, txt

I have a text file with 500k rows. In each line there are 47 words.
I want to add the letter 'C' to the 46th word in every line except the first line using linux (the first line is the table title).

For example:
ID FID IID ..... number_center age 
1 1001 807 ..... 10960 47
3 900 818 ..... 10877 51

The output: **new text file**
ID FID IID ..... number_center age 
1 1001 807 ..... **C**10960 47
3 900 818 ..... **C**10877 51

I tried to find the answer but did not find one.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Using awk, set the 46th space delimited field (46th word) to "C" plus the 46th field. Print the line with shorthand 1. Ignore the first line with NR>1.

```
awk 'NR>1 { $46="C"$46 }1' filename
```